# Other ways to stop gradle from building?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I have a project on Android Studio that takes a very long time to build.When  I click on run  button, the gradle starts immediately to build.

But sometimes I decide to make some small changes on my code. Or sometimes, I had chosen the wrong emulator.

I know I can interrupt the building process by clicking on the cross on the loading bar but **are there better ways to do stop the gradle from building that are easy and fast?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call `./gradlew --stop` command in terminal; it will kill all the processes;

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can stop gradle building by stopping java from task manager.